# does pandoc have option for putting multiple "pages" per "sheet"?

Tags: pdf, pandoc

I've been using a shell script with pandoc to create multiple page pdf files.  I can specify the size of the page... but if we consider this "page" to be a sheet of paper (the pdf gets printed onto paper)... I want to actually have multiple pages per sheet - 2 pages on each side of the side of the paper.  4 pages get printed to each sheet of paper (and the paper gets folded in half).

Depending on the style of printing, the ordering of pages is different:

- for "booklet" printing where all the pages are stacked together and then folded once together, the page ordering of an 8-page (2 sheets of paper) document would be pages 8 & 1, on the back of that pages 2 & 7, on the next sheet pages 6 & 3, and on its back 4 &5. [image: ordering of pages for booklet-style printing]
- for "book" style printing, where each sheet gets folded on its own, and then the folded sheets placed together, the order is different: page 4&1 with 2&3 on the back, and the next sheet pages 8 & 5 on one side with 6 & 7 on the other.

The desktop publishing program called Scribus (among other design-to-print softwares) has functionality for ordering the pages like this (for reference of the intent which I describe [this article](https://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/Making_a_booklet_with_Scribus_and_Adobe_Reader) describes the situation).  But I don't want to use a GUI like Scribus.  I'm writing the pages in markdown in Vim and generating the pdf from the command line.

Does pandoc have a way of ordering pages like this?

Comment: I've been looking through https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html and haven't found anything helpful for this.

Comment: @KJ it might be that pandoc can NOT do this... your comment is super helpful... particularly giving me the language "imposition" and "n-up print compositing"... and it looks like I'll be going the `tex` route via stuff like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246058/imposition-for-an-8-page-booklet-using-pgfpages.  **If you re-post your comment as an answer I'll accept it!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you state in comments "It might be that pandoc can NOT do this" without some TeX fettling.

I had previously given an answer with visuals of flat in TeX eXchange to a versatile 32-Up page way imposition can be done in LaTeX (and thus an 8 page should not be a problem by trimming down the answer)

see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/494047/a-tex-script-to-impose-multiple-layout-signatures-optionally-saddle-stitch-fro/494232#494232

Simple Imposition (booklets and n-up print compositing) can be done by other PDF orientated CLI tools that Pandoc uses but the last time I built a LaTeX program (Linked Above) it was a pain to get right.

More recently I wrote similar function to work inside SumatraPDF reader and for that I used simple CMD batch commands via either N-Up-PDF or cPDF as they do the basic stuff like rotate join 2 and reorder to booklets but you may need to adapt to suit your own use.

My RTFManual (Rich Text Format) for install/usage are in PDF @
https://github.com/GitHubRulesOK/MyNotes/raw/master/AppNotes/SumatraPDF/Addins/N-Up-PDF/N-Up-PDF.pdf